# How to run a python script in aws lambda /tmp directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, subprocess

I have downloaded a script from git into `/tmp` directory and I need to run the script in lambda. My handler looks like this:

```
def handler(event, context):
  process = subprocess.run("/tmp/my_script.py", env = os.environ, stdout=None, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

However, `my_script.py` has some external dependencies, such as `gevent`.

```
# my_script.py
import gevent
...
```

When running in lambda, I got the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent'
```

I have packaged the `gevent` module in the zipped file uploaded to lambda, which I believe they are under `/var/task`. How can I let `my_script.py` in `/tmp` directory know where to look for the dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try inserting /var/task into the path, like so:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../var/task')))

import gevent
```

Assuming the script above is in /tmp and gevent module is in /var/task.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the problem is that the script is cloned from git and I cannot edit it. Or should I even edit it (That seems hacky)? I was wondering if there is a way to specify the path when calling subprocess maybe?

Comment: Problem solved! Adding "PYTHONPATH" = "/var/task" in env solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding "PYTHONPATH" = "/var/task" in env.

```
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = "/var/task"
process = subprocess.run("/tmp/my_script.py", env = os.environ, stdout=None, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```